# Upload file with multipart POST request using Apache Http Async Client

Tags: java, apache, http, multipart

I am trying to upload a 260k image file as part of multipart form using Apache HttpAsyncClient library.

I create my form this way:

```
val multipartEntityBuilder = new MultipartEntityBuilder
multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", file)
val multipartEntity = multipartEntityBuilder.build()
```

And then I receive a ContentTooLongException when performing request basically because of this line in the library's source code:
https://github.com/apache/httpclient/blob/4.5.3/httpmime/src/main/java/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartFormEntity.java#L102

I searched a lot, but didn't find any explanation why this limitation for contentLength is present in code. Maybe someone could explain it? And my second  question: what is the proper way to make an upload request for a file larger than 25 kb?

Thanks!

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/master/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/entity/mime/MultipartFormEntity.java#L95-L105 

And explanation: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPASYNC-163

Comment: And the suggestion is to indeed use the BufferedHttpEntity: 

```One should either build a custom `HttpAsyncRequestProducer` capable of producing multipart content asynchronously or wrap `MultipartFormEntity` with `BufferedHttpEntity` if they do not mind buffering multipart content in memory prior to writing it out to an asynchronous I/O channel.```

Answer (score 10):

Found the solution: create inputStream over file and wrap the multipart entity with BufferedHttpEntity and then pass this buffered entity to request:

```
val multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", new FileInputStream(file), ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, name)
val multipartEntity = multipartEntityBuilder.build()
val entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(multipartEntity)
```

Comment: This loads the whole file in memory so uploading a 50gb file results in an out of memory error, any way to avoid it?