# MultipartFormEntity - Content too long

Tags: java, http, multipart, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpasyncclient

I'm using Java with HttpAsyncClient, and trying to make a post request to a server using multipart/form. There are two parameters: one is just a string, while the second one is a fie/byte array. When I need to perform requests with large size byte arrays, I get the following exception: org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException: Content length is too long.

Is there any way to overcome this issue? How could I make a large sized request with multipart/form using Java and this entity?

Here is some of my code:

```
final HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
final HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .addTextBody("name", fileName).addBinaryBody("file", rawContent, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, fileName)
                .build();
post.setEntity(entity);
return client.execute(post, null);
```

Where rawContent is just a byte array.

Comment: Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763042/upload-file-with-multipart-post-request-using-apache-http-async-client

Answer (score -1):

Answer to this question 'Is there any way to overcome this issue? ' : 
 you can try this code in your 'MultipartFormEntity' class

```
@Override
     public InputStream getContent() throws IOException {
         if (this.contentLength < 0) {
            throw new ContentTooLongException("Content length is unknown");
        } else if (this.contentLength > 25 * 1024) {
             throw new ContentTooLongException("Content length is too long: " + this.contentLength);
        }
         final ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         writeTo(outstream);
         outstream.flush();
         return new ByteArrayInputStream(outstream.toByteArray());
     }

     @Override
     public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
         this.multipart.writeTo(outstream);
     }

 }
```

Comment: MultipartFormEntity is not my class, its an apache class used with Http Client. I'm pretty sure this code you just posted is already present there.